# Mapview running inside didupdatelocation won't let user scroll around map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cllocationmanager

I have a Google Map view that centers on the users location each time the location manager receives an updated position. However I want the user to be able to freely pan/zoom around the map without the camera position jumping back to the users location every second or so.

I have set .isMyLocationEnabled to false as I have designed a custom icon (its a ship in my case) to represent the users location.

Furthermore I have created my own button to allow the user to pan back to the users last location (I am not using googles built in location button for the above reasons). This is not included in the example code but it does work fine.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

if let location = locations.last {

self.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15)
self.mapViewHere.isMyLocationEnabled = false // don't want the standard blue dot or location button
self.mapViewHere.camera = self.camera

/// plot our custom GMSMarker here
let currentPosition = GMSMarker()
currentPosition.map = nil // clear the last location
currentPosition = GMSMarker(position: location.coordinate)
currentPosition.icon = myCustomMarker.png
currentPosition.rotation = (locationManager.location?.course)!
currentPosition.map = self.mapViewHere


      } // end locations.first
}// end location manager
```

Because I am plotting the user location with a custom GMSMarker which is called in didUpdateLocations I didn't think that stopping the update function would be the answer as I would like this to continue even when the user zooms/pans.

So in summary; is it possible to show a map that initially centers on the users location (and updates as the device moves) but whenever the user pans/zooms around the mapview should not automatically return to the users location as soon as the didUpdateLocations fires? The User should be able to trigger a return to the initial state by pressing a custom button.

I am developing my app with Xcode and Swift 4.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my question with much appreciated guidance from Perth iOS developers group;

First define a Boolean variable;

```
var auto: Bool = true
```

Listen for user actions and adjust the variable accordingly:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
    if gesture {
        self.auto = false
        print("map view moved, self.auto set to \(self.auto)")
    }
}
```

And use this variable inside locationManager didUpdateLocation to effectively ignore the map redrawing at users locations when didUpdateLocation fires.

```
if self.auto {
      print("self.auto is true, back to auto-camera-tron")

    self.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 15)
}
```

My custom location icon will keep drawing on didUpdateLocation as long as it is declared before `if self.auto`

Lastly, I can set my custom Location button to return to centering on user location by simply changing `self.auto = true`